# playing sound files based on xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xna, mp3, wav

I'm making part of a musical typing game, and while I've created some code that will play songs that are already loaded into the XNA Content Manager, I'm trying to create something that can play MP3 and WAV based on XML files.
This is what I have for "hard-coded" songs:

```
    Song music;
    SoundEffect effect;

    Dictionary<string, SoundEffect> effectlist = new Dictionary<string, SoundEffect>();
    Dictionary<string, Song> songlist = new Dictionary<string, Song>();

    public Audio()
    { 
    }

    public void playSong(string songName)
    {
        songlist.TryGetValue(songName, out music);
        MediaPlayer.Play(music);
    }
    public void playEffect(string eftName)
    {
        effectlist.TryGetValue(eftName, out effect);
        effect.Play();
    }


    public void addSong(string aKey, Song aSong)
    {
        songlist.Add(aKey, aSong);
    }
    public void addEffect(string iKey, SoundEffect anEffect)
    {
        effectlist.Add(iKey, anEffect);
    }
```

I only know the basics of XML, like displaying text from an XML file in a console application. How can I use XML to play sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use XML to play sounds, you can use XML to data drive your application so that you can play sounds based on the content of the xml file.

For example, say you had something like

```
<songs>
    <song name="songA" file="1.mp3" />
    <song name="songB" file="2.mp3" />
    <song name="songC" file="3.mp3" />
</songs>
```

You can read the xml into something like an xDocument, and when your application requests that you play "songA", you can lookup that song in your xDocument and play the associated music file.

This lets you change the behaviour of your application through configuration rather than having everything hard-coded.

Edit: Rough code example so you get the idea...

```
   private XDocument m_Songs;
     public Audio()
    { 
         m_Songs = XDocument.Load("My XML Source");
    }


    public void playSong(string songName)
    {
        XElement match = m_Songs.Descendants()
            .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "song")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "songName");

        if (match == null)
            return;

        songlist.TryGetValue(match.Attribute("file").Value, out music);
        MediaPlayer.Play(music);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it. Could you explain more about what this example does? I have no idea about using XDocument and XElement.

Comment: The constructor parses an XML document into memory encapsulated in an object of type XDocument. When a call to playsong() is made, the LINQ query searches the XML (via the XDocument) for a matching song name. If it is found, it passes the name file associated to the song name to your original code. Not knowing what you store to identify a song, this is a bit contrived - but it simply so you get the idea about how it works. If you want to know how to use Linq, google 101 linq samples - if you want to learn to use XDocument - you should probably look it up on MSDN.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. This will be a big help!

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with this answer, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. Good luck!